# Does adding "minifyEnabled true" and 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' obfuscate the sqlite database and make it incompatible with previous versions?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sqlite, proguard, android-obfuscation

I'm submitting an update for my android app and all previous versions did not have these two settings. The database remains the same, but if the names are obfuscated, I'm worried that the user's data will be lost. In other words, I'm worried that the obfuscated names will clash with the true names and the database will reset. Thank you for reading.

I'm using Room for my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of no one answering the question, I took a measured risk, and I am going to share my findings. Prior to the risk, I discovered that I could generate a signed debuggable apk and analyze it in Android Studio. The analysis confirmed that only the java code was obfuscated and the database naming was untouched. I felt the risk was measured enough to submit a signed apk with the newly obfuscated code as an update...

...and so far, the app's update was successful. No complaints. The data was safe. Now, even though this worked today, I cannot know if they'll change it in the future so proceed with caution.